# How do i perform/use a median on a set of results in apache solr?

Tags: solr, median

Given a set of rows as output, how to use a solr median on it to get the median value?

Comment: Get the total number of hits, request the document at rows/2 sorted by the field you want to have the median for?

Comment: Thanks, understood it. However, was searching if solr supports a built-in median function like percentile

Comment: The stats component supports percentile, so if you want to get it directly without the document's context, you can use `percentile=50` I'd think: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/the-stats-component.html